# How to remove the margin below a table within a body for a transactional email?

Tags: html, css

I need to use the table format

I'm using `margin:0` and `padding:0` for the body but I don't understand why it is not working.

I would really appreciate the help

Here is the HTML code below

```
<body>
            <table class="emailContent" role="presentation">
              <!-- Header-->
              <tr>
                <td class="emailHeader">
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!-- Footer -->
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class="emailFooter"
                    role="presentation">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>   
</body>
```

I already tried various alternatives and it's not working. This is the CSS Code

```
<style>
    /* Elements */
        body{
         width: 100% !important;
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         background-color: #F4F4F7;
         color: #51545E;
        }
        /* Classes */
      .emailContent{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }  
      /* HEADER */
       .emailHeader{
         text-align: center;
         padding: 25px 0;
         background-color: #eeecec;
       }
       /* CONTENT */
       .emailMessage{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
       }
       .emailmessCont{
       width: 570px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 0;
       }
       .text{
         padding: 25px;
       }
       .emailFooter{
        width: 570px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #eeecec;
        color: #A8AAAF;
        min-width:100%;
        max-width:100%;
       }
       .lastP{
         padding-bottom:25px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEC;
       }
    </style>
```

Thank you for any possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start an HTML Project. It is recommended for you to implement a
CSS Reset code. It is widely available over the internet.

Source:https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

This will allow you to write custom code without any such hiccups. Just add this CSS in your project. It should be the first CSS in your project. All other CSS files should come below it.

```
<style>
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote: before, blockquote: after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
</style>
```